# Oracle Converting String(date with timezone) to date

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

how do i convert a string i got from an XML result into an oracle date (TO_DATE)

> 1980-10-05T23:30:00+08:00

Thanks

Comment: What date format are you expecting to have, provide the desired mask.. ie. 20-DEC-2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
select to_date(substr('1980-10-05T23:30:00+08:00', 1, 19), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS' ) from dual;
```